# Adding member to a Google group using Google API

Tags: google-api, workspace, google-directory-api

I'm trying to add email ids to a Google group using google APIs and Python3. I need help, figuring out what scopes it needs since I am getting the error:
Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential.

My code:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import os.path

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user']


def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Admin SDK Directory API.
    Prints the emails and names of the first 10 users in the domain.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
        print(creds)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'client_secrets.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    service = build('admin', 'directory_v1', credentials=creds)
    group_result = service.groups().insert(body={
                         'groupKey': 'with-automated-addition-of-members@googlegroups.com', # group key
                         'email': 'sumukhrajubhat2701@gmail.com' # user email who need to insert in google groups
                      }).execute() 
    print(group_result)
```

Anyone please help me with the issue.

Comment: Here are the [scopes](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/members/insert) but what type of authentication credentials are you using? e.g API Key, ServiceAccount + JSON Key? Also, is this a Google Workspace environment?

Comment: I've downloaded the OAuth 2.0 Client ID into a json format and storing it in client_secrets.json. Isn't that sufficient because I'm getting a new error:

googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 404 when requesting https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups?alt=json returned "Domain not found.". Details: "[{'message': 'Domain not found.', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'notFound'}]">

This seems to be due to service.groups.insert() from the above code.

Also is my way correct to insert a given email id to th a given ggroup?

Appreciate you time, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can always check the docs for each method to see what scope it requires.  In your case
[groups.insert](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/groups/insert) requires one of the following scopes.

[image]

Comment: Appreciate the answer and your time, thanks. 

I'm getting a new error: googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 404 when requesting admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups?alt=json returned "Domain not found.". Details: "[{'message': 'Domain not found.', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'notFound'}]"> This seems to be due to service.groups.insert() from the above code. Also is my way correct to insert a given email id to th a given ggroup?

Comment: Make sure your authorizing the application with a user on your workspace domain. that has access